# XCode Organizer export project not ipa after iPhone X update

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, ipa

I update my project to work with iPhone X. Biggest change I did was creating LaunchImage asset and using it on Launch Images Source. Other change was I update "Builds For" version from 8.0 to 9.0 on storyboard. Now after I archive my project and try to export in Organizer. Whole project is exported (With files) not the ipa. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can we see screenshot how they have exported?

Comment: Sorry I can't share it because It is a company project but I can say that It has usr, application, "Main project name", "Sub project name", "Other sub project name".